# How can I set a formula to return "X", when 3 conditions are not matching?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I'll try to be specific. In the attached reference trix (Google sheet), there are 3 sheets,

1. Login Sheet- where an email address, logs in on a certain date
2. Schedule- schedule of the email address, for a week
3. Attendance- where I want the attendance to be marked automatically, based on the inputs on "Login Sheet"

So far, I've managed to do the following (with many help which I received here):

1. Check if the email address is on Leave/Off (in the Schedule sheet) - Then return- Leave/Off
2. Check if an email is logged in ("login" in the Login Sheet) on a particular date - Then return "Present"

Here is where I'm stuck and need help -
When an email is scheduled but not logged in - As of now it shows #N/A'no match' (refer to D5,D6 within Attendance), I want this to return "Absent"

Here is the formula I've used so far:
`=Ifs(Vlookup($A2,Schedule!$A:$E,4,0)="Leave","Leave",Vlookup($A2,Schedule!$A:$E,4,0)="Off","Off",countifs('Login response'!$D:$D,D$1,'Login response'!$B:$B,$A2,'Login response'!$C:$C,"login")>0,"Present")`

[The Reference Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QOwruWCLkByn_14Rsc1V4_hixg5JapLKFZ0mOd3BfPs/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another condition in your function to check for absence
replace your function from

```
=Ifs(Vlookup($A2,Roster!$A:$E,4,0)="Leave", "Leave",
Vlookup($A2,Roster!$A:$E,4,0)="Off", "Off",
countifs('Login response'!$D:$D,D$1,'Login response'!$B:$B,$A2,'Login response'!$C:$C,"login")>0,"Present"
)
```

To

```
    =Ifs(Vlookup($A2,Roster!$A:$E,4,0)="Leave", "Leave",
Vlookup($A2,Roster!$A:$E,4,0)="Off", "Off",
countifs('Login response'!$D:$D,D$1,'Login response'!$B:$B,$A2,'Login response'!$C:$C,"login")>0,"Present",
countifs('Login response'!$D:$D,D$1,'Login response'!$B:$B,$A2,'Login response'!$C:$C,"login")=0,"Absent",
)
```

Comment: don't forget to mark it as answered and upvote. same goes to your previous post, you haven't marked it as answered. And upvoting is the best way to say thanks.

Comment: Hi usmanhaq, thank you for the guidelines. I've now marked both of the questions as answered. And additionally, I've been upvoting the answers that helped, but it seems my vote is invisible, because of low rep. Thanks again, and have a great day!

Comment: You can earn reputation by marking the questions you have asked as answered and you will get reputation, on the other hand you can participate in the community and answer somone's question to earn a little more reputation, i think you can upvote at reputation of 15 or more.